# JavaFX Update TextField in Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, task

I have a problem with my application JavaFX.

Image: https://picload.org/image/rlwpwdgi/javafx.png

With the button (1) showing the second window.
With the key (2) start the search in a path.
I need that the TextField (3) update as searching finds files.
In the Controller class of the second window, the button (2) perform this method.

```
public void startSuchen() {

    String text = textFieldPfad.getText();
    if (text.length() > 0) {

        dateiGef = 0;
        dateiGes = 0;

        listf(pfad);

        textFieldDateiGef.setText(String.valueOf(dateiGef));
        textFieldDateiGes.setText(String.valueOf(dateiGes));        

    }

}
```

And this is the procedure `listf`:

```
private void listf(File directory) {

    try {

        File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fileList) {

            // Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            //      @Override
            //      public void run() {
            //          textFieldDateiGef.setText(String.valueOf(getDateiGef()));
            //          textFieldDateiGes.setText(String.valueOf(getDateiGes()));
            //      }
            //  });

            // Thread thrd = new Thread() {
            //      public void run() {
            //          Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            //              @Override
            //              public void run() {
            //                      textFieldDateiGef.setText(String.valueOf(getDateiGef()));
            //                  textFieldDateiGes.setText(String.valueOf(getDateiGes()));
            //              }
            //          });
            //      }
            // };
            // thrd.start();

            if (file.isFile()) {

                dateiGes += 1;

                String fileName = file.getName().toLowerCase();
                String nome = textFieldName.getText().toLowerCase();

                Pattern r = Pattern.compile(nome);
                Matcher m = r.matcher(fileName);
                if (m.find()) {
                    dateiGef += 1;
                }

            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(file);
            }

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The commented lines are my tests to update the GUI, I also tried with the Task, but unfortunately it does not work. Someone please help me understand why?

**Here is the solution:**

```
public void startSuchen() {

    String text = textFieldPfad.getText();
    if (text.length() > 0) {

        dateiGef = 0;
        dateiGes = 0;

        // Solution
        new Thread(() -> listf(pfad)).start(); 
        // End Solution    

        textFieldDateiGef.setText(String.valueOf(dateiGef));
        textFieldDateiGes.setText(String.valueOf(dateiGes));        

    }

}
```

And this is the procedure `listf`:

```
private void listf(File directory) {

    try {

        File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fileList) {

            // Solution
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textFieldDateiGef.setText(String.valueOf(getDateiGef()));
                    textFieldDateiGes.setText(String.valueOf(getDateiGes()));
                }
            });
           // End Solution

            if (file.isFile()) {

                dateiGes += 1;

                String fileName = file.getName().toLowerCase();
                String nome = textFieldName.getText().toLowerCase();

                Pattern r = Pattern.compile(nome);
                Matcher m = r.matcher(fileName);
                if (m.find()) {
                    dateiGef += 1;
                }

            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(file);
            }

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Many thanks to **James_D**

Comment: Any error/exceptions thrown by Java? Also I would suggest using debug points

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am not getting no errors from Java, even with debugging. Just noticed that the code that should execute the Thread does not run and I can't figure out why.

Comment: As far as I can see,  the `Platform.runLater` method might not be executing. Also I noticed here, inside your `Platform.runLater` method you are again creating a thread with runnable. I think I could have avoided the outer thread creating: i.e. 'Thread thrd = new Thread()' part. Just like you have done in the firts case

Comment: I think you misread the code. The commented lines are two separate tests. I have not created a Thread inside `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: Uncomment the `Platform.runLater()` block, and execute the entire `listf` method in a background thread (replace `listf(pfad)` with `new Thread(() -> listf(pfad)).start();`)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. Your proposal worked out great. Thanks again.